# Display HTML content in a Custom notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible to build a custom notification that display HTML content ?

I saw that it's possible to build custom notification using RemoteViews, will it be possible to have WebView embedded in a RemoteViews, and pass it as a custom view to the notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sadly this is impossible :(

Custom notifications can only contain RemoteViews which only can hold a certain subset of all views like Buttons, TextViews, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but you should be able to style your notification with HTML tags, or add link to it. Here is the nice article on how to style notification with HTML: https://itnext.io/android-notification-styling-cc6b0bb86021

In short you should be able to do something like this:

```
val styleNotificationWithHtml = Html.fromHtml(yourNotification, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```